# Testing Application/Database for Multilingual Support

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm trying to find a chart or page that lists letters or alphabets for many common world languages. The idea is to copy the text into my application to make sure it is correctly working with and storing non-latin characters.

Comment: This will interest you: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/utf8.html

I found this by searching for "utf8 examples" on Google

Answer (score 0):

Take some paragraph, go to http://www.google.com/language_tools and you can get it in some tens of languages, including non-latin characters ones.